# How to create VHS effect on iOS using GPUImage or another library

Tags: ios, video, gpuimage, effect

I am trying to make a VHS effect for an iOS app, just like in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ipML-T5yDk

I want to realize this effect with the less effect possible to generate less CPU charge.

Basically what I need is to crank up the color levels to create a "chromatic aberration", change Sharpen parameters, and add some gaussian blur + add some noise.

I am using GPUImage. For the Sharpen and Gaussian blur, easy to apply.

I am having two problems:
1) For the "chromatic aberration", the way they do it usually is to duplicate three times the video, and put Red to 0 on one video, blue to 0 on another one, and green to 0 on the last one, and blend them together (just like in the tutorial). But doing this in an iPhone would be too CPU consuming.

> Any idea how to achieve the same effect withtout having to duplicate the video and blend it =

2) I also want to add some noise but do not know which GPUImage effect to use. Any idea on this one too ?

Thanks a lot,

Sébastian

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Not really :( I just added some sharpness but it still does not create a noisy image

Comment: Hey @SébastianCizoo, Did you find your solution ?

Answer (score 4):

(I'm not an iOS developer but I hope this can help someone.)

I wrote a VHS filter on Windows, this is what I did:

1. Crop the video frame to 4:3 aspect ratio and lower the resolution to 360*270.
2. Lower color saturation, and apply a color matrix to reduce green color to 93% (so the video will look purple).
3. Apply a convolve matrix to sharpen the video frame directionally. This is the kernel I used:

> ```
>     0    -0.5    0      0
>  -0.5     2.9    0   -0.5
>     0    -0.5    0      0
> ```

4. Blend a real blank VHS footage to your video for the noise (search for "VHS overlay" on YouTube).

Video: [Before](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U6wO-7Ws3Kk) [After](https://vimeo.com/314675643)
Screenshot: [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIzOC.jpg) [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfyJj.jpg)

The CPU and GPU consumption is ok. I apply this filter to real time camera preview on my old windows phone (with Snapdragon 808), and it works fine.

Code (C#, using Win2D library for GPU acceleration, implementing Windows.Media.Effects.IBasicVideoEffect interface):

```
public void ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context)    //This method is called each frame
{
    int outputWidth = 360;    //Output Resolution
    int outputHeight = 270;

    IDirect3DSurface inputSurface = context.InputFrame.Direct3DSurface;
    IDirect3DSurface outputSurface = context.OutputFrame.Direct3DSurface;

    using (CanvasBitmap inputFrame = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, inputSurface))    //The video frame to be processed
    using (CanvasRenderTarget outputFrame = CanvasRenderTarget.CreateFromDirect3D11Surface(canvasDevice, outputSurface))    //The video frame after processing
    using (CanvasDrawingSession outputFrameDrawingSession = outputFrame.CreateDrawingSession())
    using (CanvasRenderTarget croppedFrame = new CanvasRenderTarget(canvasDevice, outputWidth, outputHeight, outputFrame.Dpi))    
    using (CanvasDrawingSession croppedFrameDrawingSession = croppedFrame.CreateDrawingSession())
    using (CanvasBitmap overlay = Task.Run(async () => { return await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(canvasDevice, overlayFrames[new Random().Next(0, overlayFrames.Count - 1)]); }).Result)    //"overlayFrames" is a list containing video frames from https://youtu.be/SHhRFU2Jyfs, here we just randomly pick one frame for blend
    {
        double inputWidth = inputFrame.Size.Width;
        double inputHeight = inputFrame.Size.Height;
        Rect ractangle;

        //Crop the inputFrame to 360*270, save it to "croppedFrame"
        if (3 * inputWidth > 4 * inputHeight)
        {
            double x = (inputWidth - inputHeight / 3 * 4) / 2;
            ractangle = new Rect(x, 0, inputWidth - 2 * x, inputHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            double y = (inputHeight - inputWidth / 4 * 3) / 2;
            ractangle = new Rect(0, y, inputWidth, inputHeight - 2 * y);
        }
        croppedFrameDrawingSession.DrawImage(inputFrame, new Rect(0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight), ractangle, 1, CanvasImageInterpolation.HighQualityCubic);

        //Apply a bunch of effects (mentioned in step 2,3,4) to "croppedFrame"
        BlendEffect vhsEffect = new BlendEffect
        {
            Background = new ConvolveMatrixEffect
            {
                Source = new ColorMatrixEffect
                {
                    Source = new SaturationEffect
                    {
                        Source = croppedFrame,
                        Saturation = 0.4f
                    },
                    ColorMatrix = new Matrix5x4
                    {
                        M11 = 1f,
                        M22 = 0.93f,
                        M33 = 1f,
                        M44 = 1f
                    }
                },
                KernelHeight = 3,
                KernelWidth = 4,
                KernelMatrix = new float[]
                {
                        0,   -0.5f,    0,     0,
                    -0.5f,    2.9f,    0, -0.5f,
                        0,   -0.5f,    0,     0,
                }
            },
            Foreground = overlay,
            Mode = BlendEffectMode.Screen
        };

        //And draw the result to "outputFrame"
        outputFrameDrawingSession.DrawImage(vhsEffect, ractangle, new Rect(0, 0, outputWidth, outputHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to achieve such a thing I can see some piece of code and if possible could you publish a gif or a short video to see a result of at least several seconds?

Comment: There is no way to do it with a 3x3 kernel?

Comment: @Paul Try { -3, 0, 4, -3, 0, 4, -3, 0, 4 }